# Generate n random bytes based on m-byte seed in Java

Tags: java, random, random-seed

I'd like to **generate *n* random bytes from a given *m*-byte seed**. The generated sequence has to be **reproducible**; for the same seed the same sequence has to be generated. ***n*** can be either **higher** or **lower** than ***m***.

The two following trivial approaches that are coming to my mind are biased:

- Hash the *m* bytes to create a long seed to feed a new `java.util.Random` generator. *Problem:* I discard entropy if n<8, as the default Random seed in Java is a 8-byte long.
- Hash the *m* bytes to generate some "random" data. *Problem:* this cap *n* to some value (20 for SHA1 for example).

Is there a standard way of doing this? I did not see any relevant class in `java.security`, but I guess this is a basic need for cryptography?

*Note*: I do not need "crypto-level extra-secure" random, just random that passes basic statistical randomness tests. Also I'd prefer relying on standard code instead of having to code everything by myself.

*Edit*: `java.security.SecureRandom(byte[] seed)` does not fit the bill, the generated sequence is purely random and does not depend only on the seed (at least on my JVM, but I'd like to have a predictable result).

Comment: A hacky approach is to use the second option and just iterate over it as needed. Depends on the range of n, you may find a collision (quite unlikely with long hash like SHA512), your sequences will converge ... (WARNING: it's very unsecure, but should be good enough for your question)

Comment: To prevent collision, I could hash the result with the initial seed to seed the next step. That's an idea indeed, even though with all those hashing the performance may not be ideal.

Comment: ah, true, forgot 'bout that possibility. with that you could probably use shorter/simpler hashes.

Comment: Use a stream cipher like RC4? What's the order of the sizes of m and n? bytes, kB, TB?

Comment: @Ishtar _n_ and _m_ are in the order of the kb (let's say between 10 and 1000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For the record*, a (rather slow) solution as discussed above:

```
    public byte[] rand(byte[] seed, int n) {
        try {
            byte[] data = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream ret = new ByteArrayOutputStream(n);
            while (ret.size() < n) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
                md.update(seed);
                if (data != null)
                    md.update(data);
                data = md.digest();
                ret.write(data, 0, Math.min(n - ret.size(), data.length));
            }
            return ret.toByteArray();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

This generates 1M "random" bytes in ~500ms, and passes very basic statistical randomness tests. Maybe picking a faster hash than SHA1 would speed-up the thing, did not investigated that.